# is it possible to create a regular array that hold arraylist objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

i tried the following

```
ArrayList<FileFilter>[] allFilters = new ArrayList<FileFilter>()[10]
```

and i get

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<FileFilter>
```

is it possible (i'm using java).
btw reason i am doing it is because i am trying to filter out files. some filters are or_filters, in which case i put them all in the same place in the regular array, and some are and_filters which are in another place in the regular array. is there any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the parentheses on the right. You are actually calling the constructor for a single instance of ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<FileFilter>[] allFilters = new ArrayList<FileFilter>[10];
```

Edit: Note that this doesn't actually create any ArrayList objects; it just creates an array of 10 references, all set to `null`. You'll have to fill in the elements of the array.

Comment: now i get "Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<FileFilter>"

Comment: Right. Get rid of the generic parameter on the right as well: `new ArrayList[10];`